# How to get record with earliest date per group

Tags: sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I need to get the earliest date from the following table based on column 'ItemNo'.

```
        ItemNo  PO_number  Date
        110913  PO-8048    9/15/2015
        110913  PO-8036    9/30/2015
        110652  PO-1011    10/19/2015
        110652  PO-1011    10/10/2015
        110009  PO-1016    7/1/2015
        110009  PO-1087    6/20/2015
        110888  PO-7171    4/1/2015
```

Your query result should be look like this.

```
        ItemNo  PO_number  Date
        110913  PO-8048    9/15/2015
        110652  PO-1011    10/10/2015
        110009  PO-1087    6/20/2015
        110888  PO-7171    4/1/2015
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what query you are using?

Comment: If the date column has a datatype of Date, you could SELECT....ORDER BY dateColumnName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of different ways you could approach this, one reasonable approach would be something like:

```
with min_rec as
(
    select  t.ItemNo, t.PO_number, t.Date, row_number() over(partition by t.ItemNo order by t.Date asc) as rn
    from    your_table t
)
select   m.ItemNo, m.PO_number, m.Date
from     min_rec m
where    m.rn = 1;
```

Leveraging a CROSS APPLY would be another approach that would work as well, though in this particular case it likely wouldn't be a better performing approach (though as always, it depends):

```
select  distinct c.ItemNo, c.PO_number, c.Date
from    your_table t
cross apply (
    select top 1 i.ItemNo, i.PO_number, i.Date
    from   your_table i
    where  i.ItemNo = t.ItemNo
    order by i.Date asc) c;
```

And naturally, you could simply use a self-joining subquery (I'll skip the example on that one).

Comment: @Allen_Delon, happy to help. If this helped solve your problem, please mark it as the answer to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Allen_Delon See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work